# Retain the last N records of each group in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df which looks like the below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF'], 'b':['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2'], 'c':[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]})

    a    b    c
0  ABC   1    0.1
1  ABC   1    0.2
2  DEF   2    0.3
3  DEF   2    0.4
4  DEF   2    0.5
5  DEF   2    0.6
```

I would like to keep the last 'n' rows of each "group" (ABC, DEF) in column 'a' with 'n' depending on the value in 'b'. my result should be a new df looking like this

```
    a    b    c
1  ABC   1    0.2
4  DEF   2    0.5
5  DEF   2    0.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `tail`:

```
df.groupby('a', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.tail(int(x['b'].iloc[0])))

     a  b    c
1  ABC  1  0.2
4  DEF  2  0.5
5  DEF  2  0.6
```

This assumes all values in col "b" for that group are equal, so the first value in that group is used to compute the tail.

---

If you need to retain an equal number of rows per group, the solution simplifies to

```
df.groupby('a').tail(n)
```

Comment: thank you! i have a column d = 'date' and want to keep the 'n' latest date rows. this seems to work

df.sort_values('date').groupby('a', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.tail(int(x['b'].iloc[0])))

Comment: @idt_tt Yeah I guess sorting by date first, then using `groupby('a', group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(...)` would work

Comment: thanks. what if i want to use the last value in col "b" after sorting by date?

Comment: @idt_tt Change `int(x['b'].iloc[0])` to `int(x['b'].iloc[-1])` where `-1` is the index of the last value.

Answer (score 2):

If b not always increasing `cumcount`

```
df=df[df.iloc[::-1,].groupby('a').c.cumcount().lt(df.b.astype(int))]
df
Out[268]: 
     a  b    c
1  ABC  1  0.2
4  DEF  2  0.5
5  DEF  2  0.6
```

Comment: But mayb `c` isnt always increasing?

Comment: @yatu then it is cumcount

Comment: But I think this still doesnt do it, this keeps all rows after the nth in each group iiuc right? op wants last n per group, n specified in `b`

Comment: @yatu so reverse the order do the same